# Triggering script or external programm on Julius speech recognition

Tags: julius-speech

I'm trying to use Julius on ubuntu. After a couple of hours I've finally made it to work.

Basically, the only thing I need it to do is to trigger a script when it recognizes a certain word (ex. "computer"). And that's the main problem. What's the best way to do it?

Also it seems like I can't manage to run Julius in a "quiet" mode

```
$ julius -quiet -input mic -C julian.jconf 2>/dev/null
```

still outputs too much information:

```
                   ..........
          reject short input = off

----------------------- System Information end -----------------------

    *************************************************************
    * NOTICE: The first input may not be recognized, since      *
    *         no initial CMN parameter is available on startup. *
    * for MFCC01*
    *************************************************************
```

> Stat: capture audio at 16000Hz
>
> Stat: adin_alsa: latency set to 32 msec (chunk = 512 bytes)
>
> Error: adin_alsa: unable to get pcm info from card control
>
> Warning: adin_alsa: skip output of detailed audio device info
>
> STAT: AD-in thread created
>
> Warning: strip: sample 0-27 has zero value, stripped
>
> pass1_best:  <s>DOWarning: strip: sample 192-444 has zero value, stripped</s>
>
> pass1_best:  <s>DO PLAY</s>
>
> sentence1:  <s>DO PLAY</s>
>
> pass1_best:
>
> sentence1:  DO PLAY
>
> pass1_best:Warning: strip: sample 406-436 has zero value, stripped

```
 ....
```

and so on.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm in the same situation. Did you find the way?

Comment: yup. Did it through php: julius -input mic -C /var/www/julius-grammar/julian.jconf -quiet | php /var/www/index.php main julius

Answer (score 1):

Normally we will be calling Julius from a script, reading the output of Julius into a variable where we can hide everything and extract only what is required using substrings and slicing. In this way you can build what is referred to as a "dialog manager" using whatever application suits your purposes such as PHP, Julia, Python and so on, taking action depending on what Julius thinks it heard from a `switch` or `if .. then .. else` structure.

A simple way to do this is using an infinite loop which only exits on a command such as "COMPUTER QUIT" or similar.

The `julius` option `-nostrip` is helpful if you get lots of `nostrip` warnings.

Once you have some experience with `julius` it is really helpful to run `julius` in server mode (described in the documentation [multiple links available at https://github.com/julius-speech/julius ] along with a sample application), which allows you to control `julius` more efficiently without having to reload between recognition events. In addition `julius` will send responses in XML format so that you can reliably read the output with a tested XML reader inside the dialog manager.